# 4 points rounded star shape

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

[image: Star with four points]

I am trying to get this star as pixel perfect as possible in CSS, here's what I tried so far, but it's a 5 angled star, and I want to have it only 4 points also how can I make the corners more rounded?

```css
#star-five {
   margin: 50px 0;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right:  100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
   border-left:   100px solid transparent;
   -moz-transform:    rotate(35deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(35deg);
}
#star-five:before {
   border-bottom: 80px solid red;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 30px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   top: -45px;
   left: -65px;
   display: block;
   content: '';
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-35deg);

}
#star-five:after {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   top: 3px;
   left: -105px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right: 100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px solid red;
   border-left: 100px solid transparent;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-70deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-70deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-70deg);
   content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="star-five"></div>
```

Comment: SVG is the way to go here...anything else would be **wayyy** to complicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you could use a gradient on the [Black Four Pointed Star](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/black-four-pointed-star/) Unicode char:

> ✦

It has some compatibility issues (mostly caused by [text-fill-color](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-fill-color)) but depending on your requirements it could get the job done.

```css
.four-point-star::after,
.four-point-star::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "\2726";
    font-size: 12rem;
}

.four-point-star::after { /* The foreground star */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,191,183,1) 20%, rgba(243,44,117,1) 70%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.four-point-star::before { /* The star shadow */
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 10px rgba(242, 96, 85, 1);
}

/* Demo styling */
body {
    background: #fbd629;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.four-point-star {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span class="four-point-star"></span>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Also I'd some fallback for IE and will be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, for this kind of shape, and inline SVG would be the simplest and the most crossbrowser solution (and with a responsive pixel perfect output).
Here is a simple inline svg code to **make a four point star filled with a gradient:**

```css
svg{
  display:block; margin:0 auto;
  width:30%; height:auto;
}
/* For the demo */ body{background: url('https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="starGrad">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(153,218,255)" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(0,128,128)"/>      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#starGrad)" d="M5 1 Q5.8 4.2 9 5 Q5.8 5.8 5 9 Q4.2 5.8 1 5 Q4.2 4.2 5 1z" />  
</svg>
```

The four points are made with the path element and using [quadratic bezier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves). The star is filled with an [SVG linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an SVG. If you didn't want another http request for the svg file, you could include the svg code in the 'content' attribute:

`content: url("data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg.. code here</svg>");`

```css
.star-4-point {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml; utf8,<svg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='50px' height='50px' viewBox='0 0 50 50' style='enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;' xml:space='preserve'><path d='M25,50c0,0,1.325-8.413,8.957-16.043C41.587,26.325,50,25,50,25l0,0c0,0-8.413-1.325-16.043-8.957C26.325,8.413,25,0,25,0 l0,0c0,0-1.325,8.413-8.957,16.043C8.413,23.675,0,25,0,25l0,0c0,0,8.413,1.325,16.043,8.957C23.675,41.588,25,50,25,50'/></svg>");
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-4-point"></div>
```

Comment: You'd better add code for your SVG because you can give the same answer for every [tag:css-shapes] question and it won't be helpful at all.

Comment: 1) Unfortunately this is not displayed anywhere except Chrome (Firefox, IE, Edge). 2) Can you add gradient to your SVG like Jordi Nebot did?

Comment: Works in Chrome & FF now, haven't tested IE or Edge.

Answer (score 1):

You can get four point star using two rotated and skewed rectangles.

```css
body {
  /* just styles for demo */
  background-color: #fdd700;
}

.four-point-star {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.four-point-star:before,
.four-point-star:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fa5b88;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 141.4213%; /* 100% * √2 */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5%;
  transform: rotate(66.66deg) skewX(45deg);
}

/* the same but +90deg to rotate */
.four-point-star:after {
  transform: rotate(156.66deg) skew(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="four-point-star"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Someone else above posted a much simpler and pixel perfect way though

Comment: @Panic OK, no problem.